# how to display result data in display tag in jsp using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts

i send request to `struts` action through ajax.data come back to `ajax` .in this situation resulted data display in `jsp div` using `display tag.`please give me solution`.

```
<display:table>
<display:column></display:column>
</display:table>

var xmlHttp;
        function changFun(){
            alert(document.getElementById("datepicker").value+"abcd");
            var DateValue=document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
                xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttp==null){
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                return;
            } 
            var url="abc.jsp";
            url +="?DateValue="+DateValue;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = getDetails1;
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        function getDetails1(){
            if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){
                //document.getElementById("hidedata").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("ComId").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please give me relevant code.

Comment: @w4rumy the response data is display in jsp using displaytag

Answer (score -1):

You cannot mix jsp with ajax, ajax is client and jsp is server side. You can use controller for get data and send to view(jsp) to display the data

Comment: what you mean...you know jsp and ajax